# The dimension of the space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I need to find the dimension of the space of even smooth real valued functions of one variable belonging to the kernel of the operator:
$$\partial \circ (\partial-1)^5 \circ (\partial+1)^5,$$
$\partial$ - the differential operator.
I have no idea.

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true ... it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts. – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969)

Comment: @MartinR: I really don't know. I always write my thoughts, when I see the way. You can see my old questions.

Comment: Perhaps start with simpler cases: What are the solutions of $\partial f = 0$ or $(\partial -1)f = 0$ or $\partial ^2 f = 0$? What is the dimension of the solution spaces?